# R - Can I have a matrix with different number of columns for rows?

Tags: r, jags

This might be a stupid question. I have some 'NA' in a matrix, I need to put this matrix into jags model, but I want to remove those NA. Can I remove only NA but keep the rest of the data?

My data looked like the picture below. Can I have rows with different column numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

You need to impute these missing values or remote either the column or the row entirely.

Imputing missing values is as complicated as you want it to be. You'd be best of looking into the first few google searches on the topic or just using the mean value of the column.